# bad proof of discontinuity?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I think there's something wrong with my proof and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Suppose you have f(r,θ) for a function in polar coordinates. If this is a non-constant function of θ at r=0, i.e. $f(r=0,\theta)=g(\theta)$, g not constant, then the limit doesn't exist at the origin.

Alternatively, $\partial f(0,θ)/\partialθ<>0$ implies f is a non-constant function of theta at the origin, so the limit doesn't exist. It follows that it is not continuous and therefor not differentiable, yet the argument started with differentiation. Something has to be wrong here, but I'm not seeing it. Maybe I need more coffee.

Comment: Your first claim is strange.  You've written $f(r,\theta) = g(\theta)$.  (1) Did you mean $f(0,\theta) = g(\theta)$? (2) If that's either what you mean or what is implied, then either $g$ is constant or $f$ isn't a function of the plane.  Can you clarify your intent?  (perhaps you wanted to consider $g(\theta) = \lim_{r\to 0^+} f(r,\theta)$, in which case your result follows, but it's well-known that $g$ is insufficient to conclude the limit exists)

Comment: Your second claim is similarly strange.  What function of the plane, written in polar coordinates, can satisfy $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} (0,\theta) \neq 0$?  It seems necessary that this partial derivative be $0$ in order for $f$ to correspond to a function on the plane.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I was specifically considering f(r,θ)=cos2θ+2rcos3θ at the time, but am wondering about general principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the example you mentioned in the comments to talk about your question.  Specifically, we have the function
$$f_\text{car}(x,y) = \frac{x^2+2x^3}{x^2+y^2}$$
Importantly, $f_\text{car}$ is not defined at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.  By changing to polar coordinates, we find the resulting function is $$f_\text{pol}(r,\theta) = \cos^2\theta + 2r\cos^3\theta$$
and $f_\text{pol}$ is not defined at $r=0$.  However, while there's no way to extend $f_\text{car}$ to $(0,0)$, we can extend $f_\text{pol}$ from a function on $r \neq 0$ to a function $\tilde{f}_\text{pol}$ for all $(r,\theta)$ in the $r\theta$-plane by defining $$\tilde{f}_\text{pol}(0,\theta) = \lim_{r\to 0} f_\text{pol}(r,\theta) = \cos^2\theta$$

---

Now, to answer your questions:

Yes, if $\tilde{f}_\text{pol}(0,\theta)$ is not constant, then $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f_\text{car}(x,y)$ does not exist.  As you've written, if $\dfrac{\partial\tilde{f}_\text{pol}}{\partial \theta}(0,\theta)$ is not identically zero, then $f_\text{car}$ is not continuous and hence not differentiable at the origin (which makes sense, as $f_\text{car}$ isn't even defined at the origin).

Two points:

- In this sense, there's no conflict.  You're talking about two different functions, one of which is differentiable everywhere and the other which is not defined at a point.
- If $\tilde{f}_\text{pol}(0,\theta)$ is constant, then we cannot say whether $f_\text{car}$ has a limit at the origin.  This just means that the limits of $f_\text{car}$ along the **lines** through the origin are all the same, but this is well-known to be insufficient to tell whether the limit exists or not.

*One disclaimer:* My intuition is that this phenomenon of changing coordinates and "unraveling" a discontinuity might have a more appropriate explanation in the context of differential geometry, but I've very little experience in that field.  If you aren't completely comfortable with my treatment of your question here, it's possible that's what you want to investigate.